# How to understand the $2 \times 2$ matrix representation of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am reading a book which takes the following matrix representation of linear operators as common knowledge.  I am hoping someone can help me understand **why it works**, and **why can we reduce it to row echelon form in the usual way**?

> Let $T: V \to W$ be a bounded linear operator between hilbert spaces.  Then we consider the hilbert space decompositions $$V = V_0 \oplus V_1 \mbox{ where } V_0 = \ker T,V_1 =(\ker T)^\perp $$ $$W = W_0 \oplus W_1 \mbox{ where } W_1 = \mbox{im } T,W_0 =(\mbox{im } T)^\perp $$ and $T$ has the matrix represention $$ T = \begin{pmatrix} T_{00} & T_{01} \\ T_{10} & T_{11} \end{pmatrix} \mbox{ where } \begin{cases} T_{00} : V_0 \to W_0 \\ T_{10} : V_1 \to W_0 \\ T_{01} : V_0 \to W_1 \\ T_{11} : V_1 \to W_1 \\ \end{cases} $$ Furthermore, we may perform row reduction on this matrix as if the entries were ordinary numbers

Comment: In this decomposition $T_{00}$, $T_{01}$ and $T_{10}$ should all be zero though.

Comment: Yes that's a very good observation and so I will have to edit my question thanks!!

Comment: Might not have to let me read answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a notational convenience. What you need to understand is how the notation works, then you will be able to parse and prove statements about the notation. I will briefly describe how to get a "matrix of operators" and how such a matrix defines a linear operator.

We take two Hilbert spaces $V,W$ as our data as well as two decompositons $V= V_1\oplus V_2\oplus ... \oplus V_n$ and $W= W_1\oplus ... \oplus W_m$ into mutually orthogonal subspaces of $V$ (resp. $W$).

You may write every element of $v\in V$ uniquely in the form $v=v_1+...+v_n$ with $v_i\in V_i$ and $v_i\perp v_j$ for $i\neq j$. For **convenience** you can write $v$ as a row vector:
$$v=\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n\end{pmatrix}.$$
Similarly any $w\in W$ may be expanded into its $W_i$ components and also may be, for convenience, written as a row vector:
$$w=\begin{pmatrix} w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_m\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now if $T:V\to W$ is a linear operator, you have that $T(v) = T(v_1) + ... + T(v_n)$. Each $T(v_i)$ is an element of $W$ and may in turn be decomposed into the $W_j$ components, $T(v_i) = T(v_i)_1+...+T(v_i)_m$. Introduce the notation $T_{ji}(v)  := T(v_i)_j$. Then:

$$T(v)= \sum_{i=1}^nT( v_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m T_{ji}(v_i)= \begin{pmatrix}T_{11}(v_1)+...+T_{1n}(v_n)\\ T_{21}(v_1)+...+T_{2n}(v_n)\\ \vdots\\ T_{m1}(v_1)+...+T_{mn}(v_n)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}T_{11} & ... & T_{1n}\\ T_{21}&...& T_{2n}\\ \vdots & & \vdots\\ T_{m1}&...& T_{mn}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2\\ \vdots\\ v_n\end{pmatrix}$$

This is how, given an operator $T:V\to W$ and orthogonal decompositions of $V$ and $W$ the matrix of $T$ wrt this decomposition is defined. The $T_{ij}$ are maps (a priori not necessarily linear) from $V_j$ to $W_i$. The maps $T_{ij}$ are infact actually linear, which can be proven via some calculation (for example if $P_i:W\to W_i$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W_i$ then $T_{ij}= P_i\circ T\lvert_{V_i}$, which is then linear as a composition of linear maps).

In the same way if you have a matrix of linear maps $T_{ij}: V_j\to W_i$ then defining for any $v\in V$ with $v=v_1+...+v_n$:
$$T(v):= \sum_{ij}T_{ij}(v_j) =\begin{pmatrix}T_{11} & ... & T_{1n}\\ T_{21}&...& T_{2n}\\ \vdots & & \vdots\\ T_{m1}&...& T_{mn}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2\\ \vdots\\ v_n\end{pmatrix}$$
will give you a linear map $V\to W$.

Due to the way matrix multiplication works this can result in some **conceptual or notational simplification** when you are interested in looking at linear operators between two Hilbert spaces that have some orthogonal decomposition. For example if you have $T: V\to W$, $U: W\to Z$ then with $V,W, Z$ admitting an orthogonal decomposition then you have in the usual way $(U\circ T)_{ij}= \sum_k U_{ik}T_{kj}$.

As a final remark much of this also works if $V$ and $W$ are decomposed into *infinitely* many orthogonal subspaces. But now you need to add some summability considerations into the mix.